# Why onTouchEvent getPointerCount() method always returning 1?

Tags: android, view, touch-event

I'm trying just trying to make this function work but I am having troubles. When I have touch on View, getPointerCount() method always returns 0 pointers, when I touch the screen with one finger, 1. When I touch the screen with two or more fingers, it's always return 1. Have you any ideas ?

i have trying to this code,

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
        // No dragging during animation at the moment.
        // TODO: Stop animation on touch event and return to drag mode. 
        if (me.getPointerCount() >= 2) {
            mAnimate = false;
            mEnableTouchPressure = false;
            mRenderLeftPage = false;
            startCurl(CURL_NONE);
            mCurlState = CURL_NONE;
            mPageRight.setFlipTexture(false);
            mPageLeft.setFlipTexture(false);
            return false;
        } else {
            if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.e("TAG_EVENT", me.getPointerCount() + "");
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG_EVENT - 2", me.getPointerCount() + "");
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is because you should return true for the touch event to be processed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry  I am new in SO. What I meant is that maybe the problem is related that the onTouch method is not returning true so the touch event is not processed.

From the docs (View.onTouch()): 
 **Returns**
_True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise._
So what you can try is returning true in the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the about `MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK`. For catching the action of multiTouch you can use the following code :

```
int action = (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) % 5
switch(action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        System.out.println(motionEvent.getPointerCount());
        break;
}
```

Comment: Don't think this is the case (in recent versions of the API anyway).  ACTION_DOWN events always have a pointer count of 1 (even if you mask out the right bits with ACTION_MASK)